# Repartioning/Removing Old Linux Distributions

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I have started using a laptop again that I used to have a lot of Linux installations on, and I am trying to remove all of those. I can't figure out how to remove these last partitions. I am familiar with GParted, and can use that. Can somebody just tell me which partitions I should definitely not remove (like related to Windows recovery)?

[image: Disk Manager]

Answer (score 2):

This disk is truly a mess:

You have 3 small partitions that might be an EFI and several Windows
recovery partitions. They are negligible and are not worth deleting.

One of the small partitions has the drive-letter E, no idea why.
You should remove it but leave the partition in there.

You have two large unallocated spaces that should be united into one,
which are probably the Linux distributions that you uninstalled.

I don't know whether you would like to make the unallocated space into
a separate partition, or would like to add them into C.
Let me know what you wish to do.

In any case, you cannot move unallocated space, so you need to move
the partitions themselves using a third-party bootable partition
editor. Do not change the order of the partitions.
I also suggest taking a backup of all your data.

If you don't need anything that's on the disk, you could simply boot
the Windows installation from USB, format the disk and reinstall
over the (one) resulting unallocated space.
This would clean out everything.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I deleted everything except for the first two partitions using gparted, and Windows boots fine. Is this an acceptable configuration? https://imgur.com/a/7oqmhdh

Comment: Anything that works is acceptable.